# Google Endpoints & Oauth for Servlets

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

How can I secure my Google endpoints. I need to make a java client call (servlets, NOT android) into the endpoint services.

There is documentation for iOS, Javascript and Android clients, but not for java clients.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/).

Edit: here's the part on [OAuth](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2).